# How can I get Subliminal to work and then integrate it with a file manager?

Tags: command-line, nautilus, bash, thunar

I have downloaded Subliminal which is a program that downloads movie subtitles.But there are several problems: (1) when I test it at the console with a
movie that I know has an English subtitle, I get an unsatisfactory response:

```
alan@alan-Latitude-D530:~$ subliminal -l en la fin du jour.avi
usage: subliminal -l LANGUAGE [LANGUAGE ...] [-s] [-c CACHE_FILE]
                  [-p PROVIDER [PROVIDER ...]] [-m MIN_SCORE] [-a AGE] [-h]
                  [-f] [--addic7ed-username USERNAME]
                  [--addic7ed-password PASSWORD] [-q | -v]
                  [--log-file LOG_FILE] [--color] [--debug] [--version]
                  [--help]
                  PATH [PATH ...]
subliminal: error: too few arguments
```

(2) I loaded a bash script into Nautilus so that I could download subtitles by a right-click on a movie file instead of having to go to a console. But I could not get a successful download!:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 # NAME:         Get_subtitles
 # AUTHOR:       (c) 2014 Glutanimate
 # DEPENDENCIES: subiminal (https://github.com/Diaoul/subliminal)
 # LICENSE:      MIT license (http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)

 LANGUAGE="en"

 while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
     MOVIE="$1"
     subliminal "$MOVIE" -l "$LANGUAGE"
     shift
 done
```

(3) Finally,In another attempt to download the subtitle with a right-click on the movie file, I opened Thunar File Management and loaded a command into its Custom Action:

```
subliminal -f -l en --%N
```

Alas, this did  not work either!

My objective here is:

> (1) make sure that Subliminal actually is working i.e.downloads subtitles
>
> (2) integrate Subliminal with a file system so that it operates with a right-click on a movie file without have to work at the terminal

Answer (score 1):

I'm the maintainer of subliminal.

Latest version of subliminal (1.0.1 as I'm writing this) brings a lot of fixes and a brand new command line interface that is much easier to work with and nicer to look.

There is a soon-to-be-released example that integrates subliminal with the Nautilus file manager to add a right click context menu. Screenshot and install instructions are [here](https://github.com/Diaoul/subliminal/tree/develop#nautilus-integration). It features an automatic download menu, a configuration interface and a manual download interface so you're never stuck with the wrong subtitle.

Don't hesitate to open issues on the [bug tracker](https://github.com/Diaoul/subliminal/issues).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Thunar 1.6.3 in Xubuntu 14.04.1

My custom action is based on [Thunar Custom action - download subtitle with periscope](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions#download_subtitles_with_periscope)

```
subliminal %F -l en && zenity -–info –-title “Done” –-text “Subtitles downloaded successfully” || zenity –-error –-title “Error” –-text “Subtitles not downloaded successfully”
```

Note that `-l en` comes after file name. You can try running the command first before you create the custom action.

Beware when copying from Thunar documentation because double dash `--` became single dash `-` in that documentation.

Zenity is currently not showing any dialog. (I think periscope and subliminal has different return values (just my opinion)).